How to get timestamp with the hr value while using Polar package in flutter
I am using the following package for making a flutter application to record data from a Polar H10 device: https://pub.dev/packages/polar
if (availabletypes.contains(PolarDataType.hr)) {
  polar.startHrStreaming(identifier).listen((data) {
     int hr = data.samples.first.hr;
  }
}

In ecg and ACC i can get the timestamp by doing data.samples.first.timeStamp. But the same attribute is not available for hr it seems.
How do i access the timestamp sent with the hr by the Polar device?
I have seen the documentation and there is no timeStamp attribute in the constructor of PolarHRSample class. Whereas it exists in the classes of Acc and Ecg. What should i do?

As you already discovered, the flutter package Polar does not offer timestamps for Heart Rate. But neither does the official Polar BLE SDK. So there is no way to obtain a timestamp for Heart Rate, it does not exist.
